# How can call another phtml content file via ajax in magento 2 model popup?

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento2

Please can anyone suggest me to how can call phtml file content load in model popup in magento 2...

Thanks help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website helpfull to you [Example](https://webkul.com/blog/call-model-popup-magento-2/)

Comment: You give me a hint..Thanks..!!